# Remove key/value pairs in a dictionary over a certain range

Tags: python, json, loops, file, dictionary

It's been a while since I've used Python (using 3.8) and I've been trying to throw together a quick and dirty tool to read from a text file, remove key/value pairs over a certain range, and then make a new JSON file from it. I mainly am not sure how to access the indices of the key/vals of a selected range in a dictionary vs going through the entire thing in a way that I can modify anything. This is the point I got to:

```
new_data = []
with open('edu01.txt') as json_file:
    the_data = json.load(json_file)

    for obj in the_data:
        new_obj = {}
        for key, val in obj.items():
            new_obj[key] = val

        # TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
        for cut_key, cut_val in range(2, len(new_obj.items()) - 8):
            new_obj.remove(cut_key, cut_val)

        new_data.append(new_obj)
```

Comment: do you mean the keys in range or the indices of the dictionary in range will be removed?

Comment: The keys in the range. So if I had a dictionary of length 40 I want to get rid of everything from say index 2 to index n, where n is less than 40

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the use of an `OrderedDict()` when reading from your json file. In this way, you can check the index of the keys against your criteria range:

```
the_data = json.load(open('edu01.json'), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

for idx, key in enumerate(reversed(the_data.keys())):
    if idx in range(len(the_data.items()) - 2, 8, -1):
        the_data.pop(key)
```

Regular dictionaries won't preserve the order of your items. While I'm not entirely sure that `reversed()` is needed in the case of OrderedDictionaries, it's better to work backwards to ensure that you don't change the indexes as you remove them. Alternatively, you could do:

```
the_data = json.load(open('edu01.json'), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
keys_to_remove = []

for idx, key in enumerate(reversed(the_data.keys())):
    if idx in range(len(the_data.items()) - 2, 8, -1):
        keys_to_remove.append(key)

for k in keys_to_remove:
    the_data.pop(k)
```

Comment: It looks like you're onto something, but when I played around with it, the editor complained that `.keys()` won't work because `the_data` is a list

Answer (score 0):

```py
# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
        for cut_key, cut_val in range(2, len(new_obj.items()) - 8):
            new_obj.remove(cut_key, cut_val)
```

In this part, you can not unpack `range(2, len(new_obj.items()) - 8)` because, It is `range` object not `dict` object and can not know length of range is two or not(If length is two, only you can unpack).

And I think, your intention is not clear. Could you please write more detail? For example, like Input and Output example

Comment: So for example if my dictionary was something like `{ State: AB, Population: 100, State Bird: toucan, ... Thirty-seventh: UV, Thirty-eighth: WX, Thirty-ninth: YZ }`. I want to get rid of everything that starts at, say, the third index up to the 38th index so that I end up with just only `{ State: AB, Population: 100, Thirty-ninth: YZ }`.